# Notification triggered immediately and not at the time I wanted it to be triggered

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm relatively new to Android so I'm quite puzzled here...

I want a notification to be triggered at a certain time on a daily basis.

I use a Calendar class to set the time when the notification is triggered every day, and AlarmManager to set the repeating task.

The problem is, the notification is triggered when the app is initially launched and not at the pre-defined time configured in the Calendar object. When I run in debug mode, I see that I go to the setExact method.

I also created a receiver to handle the notification itself and open the MainActivity when the notification is clicked.

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .
        .
        .
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

**NotificationReceiver.java**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle("This is the title")
                .setContentText("This is the text")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.deal_icon);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        manager.notify(100, notification);
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.goldbox.goldboxdeals">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="com.sample.sample1.ApplicationHelper"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Calendar.getInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) returns a calendar at your current local time. You're then setting the time to be what you wish, with today's date. When you schedule an alarm, the date is likely in the past. The system then will trigger the alarm immediately.

I believe you should use [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). You can set the trigger / interval times. Keep in mind that your app, or even the device itself, isn't necessarily running all the time.

Comment: I did. Please look a few lines below the calendar.

Comment: Yes, but based on your question, your SDK version is > 19. "When I run in debug mode, I see that I go to the setExact method."

Thus, you're not calling setRepeating() on your test device.

Comment: Tried that as well. Same results :-(

Comment: What did you use for your `triggerAtMillis` argument? If you're using the current timestamp for that, then it will trigger immediately. You want to use a value in the future.